# N-Urns N-Color ball modelling as Markov Chain

Tags: references, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am trying to model a system which can, mostly, be simplified to elements of different groups changing groups among themselves. I want to understand how frequently the elements change group and how frequently they stay in the same group (after a large number of interactions). My initial idea was to treat it as a Ehrenfest urn problem with N-Urns and N-Colors (the initial group). A ball after being selected can change urn or stay in the same.

For example (with N=2), all the red balls start in urn 1 and all the blue balls in urn 2 (the number of blue and red balls is not necessary the same). Select randomly a ball, for example a red one from urn 1 and it can move to urn 2 with probability p (or stay with 1-p).

In my problem, I have the final state of the urns (after enough time for mixing) and try to find the transition matrix(ces) based on that.

However, I can't seem to find any source with anything that looks like my problem. All the cases I see are, in general, much simpler and I can't find a way to apply them to my problem. Is an Ehrenfest urn what I am looking for or is there any other any name? Am I missing something and is there any other way to model this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: In the interest of your question... could you please fill in some details of your problem definition? We have $N$ urns, $N$ colors: 1) In which *initial* configuration are they? 2) Which transitions are allowed? Which aren't? 3) What is the final equilibrium? (Does it matter? Why?)

Answer (score 0):

The study of the [CNO-cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) in stellar nuclear processes has some similarity with this inverse problem (using observed ratio's of C, N und O to calculate the reaction rates), although the multiple urns would make it more difficult.

**Basically you are looking for matrices such that observed final state is an equilibrium state (eigenvector with eigenvalue 1).**

---

**simple example**

With $x$ blue balls in urn 1 and $y$ blue balls in urn 2 you have an equilibrium if the ratio of fluxes is  $a/x$ from urn 1 to urn 2 and $a/y$ from urn 2 to urn 1.

Indeed observe the eigenvector and eigenvalue of the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1-\frac{a}{x} & \frac{a}{y} \\ \frac{a}{x} & 1- \frac{a}{y} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\y \end{pmatrix}  = 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

**General**

For more urns you are looking for $M v = v$ or $(M-I) v = 0$. Thus any matrix $M$ such that $(M-I)$ is made up of rows that are perpendicular to $v$ will do. So let $P$ be a n-1 x n matrix with rows perpendicular to $v$, and let $N$ be any n x n-1 matrix with at least a non-zero entry in every row. then $(N P)+I$ is a matrix with $v$ as eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

In our example this is

$$ M-I = \begin{pmatrix} b \\ c  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{x} & \frac{1}{y} \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{b}{x} & \frac{b}{y} \\  -\frac{c}{x} & \frac{c}{y} \end{pmatrix}$$

where we impose in addition $b=-c$ according to the equation of continuity (for the solution to remain physically relevant the flow out of an urn is equal to what is inside the cell urn itself, ie the sum of values in a single column equals to 1)

Comment: Let me know if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Oh! This seems promising and is similar to what I'm looking for! Do you know of any good book or articles I can read more about the mathematical side of it?

Comment: @mechanical_fan , to be honest I am not an expert and made this all up (it is an 'on the back of an envelope calculation'). But it is based on simple and basic knowledge. Therefore It would be difficult to pinpoint precisely what kind of information you would need. You have not clearly stated your problem. I can state the problem as an eigenvector problem but I actually have no idea why and what you are doing, so I can not make it more specific or useful.

Comment: To be honest, I have barely started working on the problem itself that's why it is so vague. I was mostly asking to see if there was some known model which resembles it, instead of a precise answer and calculation

Comment: @mechanical_fan, do you have anything more by now? (or would you like to chat?)